# How do I set initial default input fields, prior to "Add Property" being pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three jQuery `button` elements that work correctly. When `Add Property` is pressed, it creates 3 new input boxes. However, I would like three of the same input boxes showing before the button is pressed. How do I go about doing this? Here is my code, prior to any buttons being pressed.

```js
var name, address, city, input, inputCount = 0;

function newInput() {
    $('#box > div').hide();
    inputCount++;
    input = $('<div data-id="'+inputCount+'" id=input' + inputCount + '></div>').appendTo('#box');
    name = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_name" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' Name">').appendTo(input);
    address = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_address" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' Address">').appendTo(input);
    city = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_city" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' City">').appendTo(input);
}

function editPreviousEntry() {
    var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

    if (cId - 1 !== 0) {
        $('#box > div').hide();
        $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId - 1) + ')').show();
    }
    $('#box > div:nth-child(' + inputCount + ')').hide();
}

function editNextEntry() {
    var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

    if (cId + 1 <= inputCount) {
        $('#box > div').hide();
        $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId + 1) + ')').show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editPreviousEntry()">Edit Previous Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editNextEntry()">Edit NExt Entry</button><br/><br/>

<span id="box"></span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger newInput on document ready or window load

```
var name, address, city, input, inputCount = 0;

newInput();

function newInput() {
  $('#box > div').hide();
  inputCount++;
  input = $('<div data-id="'+inputCount+'" id=input' + inputCount + '></div>').appendTo('#box');
  name = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_name" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' Name">').appendTo(input);
  address = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_address" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' Address">').appendTo(input);
  city = $('<input type="text" name="prop_' + inputCount + '_city" placeholder="Property ' + inputCount + ' City">').appendTo(input);
}

function editPreviousEntry() {
  var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

  if (cId - 1 !== 0) {
    $('#box > div').hide();
    $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId - 1) + ')').show();
  }
  $('#box > div:nth-child(' + inputCount + ')').hide();
}

function editNextEntry() {
  var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

  if (cId + 1 <= inputCount) {
    $('#box > div').hide();
    $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId + 1) + ')').show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to trigger the newInput() on document ready? I tried to copy what you represented, but it doesn't work. I am very new to Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add newInput() like this $(window).load(function(){ newInput(); })